# Exact algorithms for a bin packing problem

Tags: matching, packing

There is a one-dimensional bin-packing problem.

- There is a collection of items that need to be divided into several groups, with a maximum of M items per group.
- Each item includes several characters, for example item1 = ABC and item2 = CDF. If item1 and item2 are assigned to the same group, then the distinct characters covered by this group is ABCDF.
- Let A be the set of all character sets. The objective is to find an optimal grouping scheme that minimizes the number of characters covered by each group.

I have tried some heuristics. Can anyone give some exact algorithms that use dynamic programming or graph matching?

Comment: Do you really want a method based on dynamic programming or graph matching? Mixed-integer programming seems to be suited for this problem

Comment: Is there a limit on the number of groups? If not, the optimal solution is to make every item a group of cardinality 1.

Comment: @prubin If I understand correctly, combining items that have the same characters improves the objective value.

Comment: That is right. Yes, the objective is to combine the items that the same characters. @RobPratt    The number of groups equal to the number of items divided by M, round to an integer number. Can we solve this problem exacly, instead of using an MIP solver?

Comment: @fontanf Since the MIP approach usually require a MIP solver, which is not available in my project. So I need some domain specific algorithms to find the exact solution.

Comment: A MIP solver is exact. It's not a heuristic, and it's fully deterministic and guaranteed to produce optimal output (within machine precision).

Comment: Why would a MIP solver not be available in your project? They're free and open-source (several times over).

Comment: @Reinderien Since it is a real time case, and the response time is very short. I am afraid the Solver computation time increases a lot along with the problem scale. The problem arises from an order picking problem. The best altervative is to solve it independent with the solver.

Comment: So your rationale has gone from "it isn't exact", to "it isn't available", to "it's too slow". "Realtime" is quite vague: do you have any _specific_ performance requirements? Problem size, timings?

Comment: For example, in most cases, the problem size is moderate, and a solver may obtain an optimal solution quickly. However, during peak promotion, the problem size may increase significantly. I am concerned that the solver may require a long time to run, which would affect the warehouse operation. Moreover, it is preferable not to rely on other third-party packages for the deployment environment. Therefore, I believe that dynamic programming or backtracking may be the best choice. @Reinderien

Comment: "Not relying on third-party packages" means you aren't allowed to use most software.

Comment: @Reinderien this kind of restriction is quite common in industry actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MIP is already exact. Let there be

- $l = 26$ letters;
- $m = 5$ maximum group items;
- $n = 7$ as an example item count, also equal to the maximum number of groups;
- $G_{i,j} \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ binary group-item assignments, $0 \le i < n$, $0 \le j < n$;
- $I_{j,k} \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ binary item-letter assignments, $0 \le j < n$, $0 \le k < l$;
- $L_{i,k}\in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ binary group-letter assignments, $0 \le i < n$, $0 \le k < l$.

Minimize
$$\sum_i \sum_k L_{i,k}$$
subject to
$$1=\sum_i G_{i,j} \;\forall j$$
$$m \ge \sum_j G_{i,j} \;\forall i$$
$$n L_{i,k} \ge \sum_j I_{j,k} G_{i,j} \;\forall i,k$$

Works fine:

```py
from string import ascii_uppercase
import scipy.sparse as sp
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint


items = (
    'ABC', 'CDF', 'EHI', 'AHP', 'EPZ', 'CIZ', 'ITW',
)

L = len(ascii_uppercase)
M = 5  # max items per group
N = len(items)


# Variables: NN item-group assignments; NL letter-group assignments
cost = np.concatenate((
    np.zeros(N*N),  # group-item assignments non-optimized
    np.ones(N*L),   # group-letter assignments minimized
))

# Every item must be assigned to exactly one group
item_excl = LinearConstraint(
    A=sp.hstack(
        (sp.eye(N),)*N + (sp.csc_matrix((N, N*L)),),
        format='csc',
    ),
    lb=np.ones(N), ub=np.ones(N),
)

# Every group can have at most M items (Kronecker)
group_capacity = LinearConstraint(
    A=sp.hstack((
        sp.kron(sp.eye(N), np.ones(N)),
        sp.csc_matrix((N, N*L)),
    ), format='csc'),
    ub=np.full(shape=N, fill_value=M),
)

# For each letter of each item, that item must have at least one group assignment that in turn has
# a compatible letter assignment
item_block = sp.dok_array((L, N))
letter_block = sp.dok_array((L, L))
n_letters = 0
for letter in ascii_uppercase:
    items_with_letter = [i for i, word in enumerate(items) if letter in word]
    if len(items_with_letter) > 0:
        item_block[n_letters, items_with_letter] = -1
        letter_block[n_letters, ord(letter) - ord('A')] = N
        n_letters += 1
item_block = sp.block_diag((item_block[:n_letters, :],)*N, format='csc')
letter_block = sp.block_diag((letter_block[:n_letters, :],)*N, format='csc')

letter_assigns = LinearConstraint(
    A=sp.hstack((item_block, letter_block), format='csc'),
    lb=np.zeros(n_letters*N),
)

result = milp(
    c=cost,
    integrality=np.ones(N*N + N*L),  # all variables integral
    bounds=Bounds(lb=0, ub=1),       # all variables binary
    constraints=(item_excl, group_capacity, letter_assigns),
)
assert result.success, result.message

item_assign, letter_assign = np.split(result.x, (N*N,))
item_assign = item_assign.reshape((N, N)).round().astype(int)
letter_assign = letter_assign.reshape((N, L)).round().astype(int)

print('Item assignments:')
print(item_assign, end='\n\n')

print('Letter assignments:')
print(letter_assign, end='\n\n')

for i_group in range(N):
    group_assigns = item_assign[i_group]
    if group_assigns.any():
        group_letters = ''.join(ascii_uppercase[i] for i in letter_assign[i_group].nonzero()[0])
        print(f'Group {i_group} has letters {group_letters}, items',
              ', '.join(items[i] for i in group_assigns.nonzero()[0]))
```

```
Item assignments:
[[1 0 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0]]

Letter assignments:
[[1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

Group 0 has letters ABCEHIPZ, items ABC, EHI, AHP, EPZ, CIZ
Group 1 has letters ITW, items ITW
Group 6 has letters CDF, items CDF
```